# How to display a mathematical equation in a pretty way in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to display a vector equation in a pretty way in a Jupyter Notebook. I am trying to achieve something like this:

[image: Vector equation]

Using the IPython.display module, I'm able to print the matrix in a pretty way. The problem is displaying "(2 * the matrix)  - (1 * another submatrix) ..." inline.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you looked into this? pytex.org

Comment: Also this: jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX/current/

Comment: PyLaTeX seems to be something I could use, however I reckon it can't be imported into Anaconda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from IPython.display import display, Math, Latex
display(Math(r'2 \cdot  \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -2 \\ \end{bmatrix} -1 \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ -3 \\ \end{bmatrix} +1 \cdot \begin{bmatrix} -3 \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} -1 \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} -4 \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}'))
```

[image]

for thicker .'s you can use \bullet instead of \cdot

Answer (score 2):

Jupyter Notebook Supports Latex:

```
$e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0$
```

https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Working%20With%20Markdown%20Cells.html#LaTeX-equations

Answer (score 1):

Using sympy is an alternative to using LaTex:

```
from IPython.display import display
from sympy import *
from sympy import init_printing
init_printing()

A = np.array([[2, 3],[6, 1]])
B = np.array([[1, 2]]).transpose()
m = Matrix(A); n=Matrix(B)
display(Eq(MatMul(m,n),m*n))
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbfcN.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use the `%%latex` magic function in a Jupyter notebook code cell. This renders the whole cell output in Latex:

```
%%latex
\begin{align} 2 \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -2 \\ \end{bmatrix} -1 \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ -3 \\ \end{bmatrix} +1 \cdot \begin{bmatrix} -3 \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} -1 \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} -4 \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} \end{align}
```

[image]

All different methods for rendering LaTeX in Jupyter are described [here](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/2.x/examples/Notebook/Display%20System.ipynb#LaTeX).

Comment: Thanks, I know, but I couldn't figure out this part  -> {bmatrix}